# Why is my code not working as intended? The error message also prints the proper output message

Tags: java

The code part here which specifically doesn't work I have commented it out.

I'm in a rush, so I will answer more in the comments.

When I type in something other than `m` or `I` for the units question, when printing the error message as it should, it also prints a statement which would be true if the program continued further if I had typed `m` or `i`.

Why? Why aren't my if else if and else not connecting properly?

Some context, I'm a novice programmer learning Java in university and this is one of my optional lab projects where we have to build a BMI calculator. A calculator working only for the metric system would be enough, but they said you could optionally add in an option to calculate it using the imperial system also, which I decided to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BmiCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //This part greets them and asks which Unit system they would like to use...
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Freddy Fazbear's BMI Calculator!");
        System.out.println("[=========================================]");
        System.out.print("What unit system do you want to use? metric or imperial (m/i)?: ");
        String units = reader.next();
        //Initializing all my variables since the Values arent getting read outside the loop without them.
        double meters, kilos, feet, lbs, bmi = 0;
        
        //Conditional set of statements which Runs if user selected "m" or the Metric system.
        if (units.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) 
        {
            //this part asks the users for height and weight and stores it in respective bariables
            System.out.print("Please enter your Height(m): ");
            meters = (float) reader.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Please enter your Weight(kg): ");
            kilos =  reader.nextDouble();
            
            //this part calculates the BMI, converts meters and kilos into feet and lbs then displays the result
            bmi = (float) (kilos / (meters * meters));
            feet = meters*3.28;
            lbs = kilos*2.2;
            System.out.println("Your BMI is ---> " + bmi);
            System.out.println("Your height in (meters) is " + meters);
            System.out.println("Your weight in (kilograms) is " + kilos);
            System.out.println("Your height in (feet) is " + feet);
            System.out.println("Your weight in (pounds) is " + lbs);
        }
        
        //Conditional set of statements which Runs if user selected "i" or the Imperial system.
        else if (units.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) 
        {
            //this part asks the users for height and weight and stores it in respective bariables
            System.out.print("Please enter your Height(feet): ");
            feet = (double) reader.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Please enter your Weight(pounds): ");
            lbs =  reader.nextDouble();
            
            ////this part calculates the BMI by converting the feet value into inches then using the standard Imperial formula
            meters = feet/3.28;
            kilos = lbs/2.2;
            //also converts feet and lbs into meters and kilos then displays the result later. 
            feet = feet*12;
            bmi = (float) 703*(lbs / (feet * feet));
            System.out.println("============================");
            System.out.println("Your BMI is ---> " + bmi);
            System.out.println("Your height in (meters) is " + meters);
            System.out.println("Your weight in (kilograms) is " + kilos);
            //converts inches to feet again to display it only as feet rather than inches.
            System.out.println("Your height in (feet) is " + feet/12);
            System.out.println("Your weight in (pounds) is " + lbs);
        }
        //error message when the user enters something else other than i or m in units variable.
        //unfortunately it doesnt work completely as intended.
        //else {
            //System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        //}
        
        //different bmi result messages based on the ranges given for BMI.
        if (bmi < 18.5) 
        {
            System.out.println("You are Underweight");
            System.out.println("Gain some weight skinny!");
        }
        else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9)
        {
            System.out.println("You are Healthy!");
            System.out.println("Keep it up buddy!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You are Overweight!");
            System.out.println("Lose some weight chubby!");
        }
        //closing the reader because of the yellow line at the top
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, you should not check for 18.5 twice, because this will get you into a mess, too. 18.5 will register as overweight, because it is not included in the second if. If you wanted to explicitly check it, you should write `if (18.5 <= bmi && bmi < 24.9)`. So watch `<` and `<=` problems. In your case above, the second if should only be `else if (bmi < 24.9)`. Another thing: In composed checks related to ranges, it's also easier only to use left-to right syntax, so never to use `>`, only `=` and `<=` and `<`,  because that way it's a lot easier to visually 'see' your ranges and later adjust them.

Comment: I did the same thing in the last else if. and also if my bmi was less than equal to 18.5 that would not be healthy though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing your `bmi` variable as 0, and still checking `if (bmi < 18.5)` after your Invalid Input print. There's nothing in your code that tells Java to stop executing at `System.out.println("Invalid Input!");` so it will just keep running.

The simplest way to get from what you have to the behaviour you want is to simply return from the main function when you receive invalid input:

```
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
    reader.close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is really simple but can you suggest any other way without using return? Ik its the most simple but I don't think we have learned about return yet in my course.

Comment: @Cyrix in that case you can do something like add `boolean validInput = false` at the start of your program and then set `validInput = true` inside your  `"m"` and `"i"` cases. This would allow you to use a check like `if (validInput && bmi < 18.5)` in your three result cases. It's a bit silly, but would work.